# Projection onto a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra, projection

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and denotes
$C := \left\lbrace \left( x , z \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \colon A x - z = 0 \right\rbrace$.

Is there any way to construct a projection map onto C?

In particular, for any $\left( u , v \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$, how to find the point $\Pi_{C} \left( u , v \right) := \left( \Pi_{C}u , \Pi_{C}v \right) \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $A \left( \Pi_{C}u \right) - \Pi_{C}v = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

If we regard $(x,z)$ as a vector in $\Bbb R^{n+m}$, then $C$ is simply the column space of the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{I\\A}
$$
The matrix of the projection onto this column space may be computed as 
$$
M[M^TM]^{-1}M^T = M[I + A^TA]^{-1}M^T
$$
That is, given a $(u,v)$, the projection is given by
$$
\pmatrix{u_{proj}\\v_{proj}} = M[M^TM]^{-1}M^T\pmatrix{u\\v}
$$